# Replacing parts of a variable and eliminating spaces

Tags: string, replace, stata

I have a large dataset in Stata and I have to clean the names in order to match the prenames later on.

A common problem in my data are umlauts, which are displayed as below:

> JEAN S ACUTE OVER E BASTIEN --> JEAN SÉBASTIEN

I can delete `ACUTE OVER` using the following command:

```
replace name=subinstr(name," ACUTE OVER ","",.)
```

However, I still have to consider the space between the `E` and `BASTIEN`. I can't just delete all spaces as there can be more than two prenames.

Is there any way I can achieve this in a fairly simple way?

Note that I do not care about the acute over the `E` as I have to replace it later anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform more than one pass to get the desired output.

For example, if the umlauts in your data are always positioned after the first name and you know what these are in advance, you could do the following:

```
clear

input str50 stringvar
"JEAN S ACUTE OVER E BASTIEN"
"JERARD DE ALOHA HEY P ARTIER"
"Etienne SOMETHING ANSEL"
end

replace stringvar = subinstr(strtrim(stringvar), " ", ";", 1)
replace stringvar = subinstr(stringvar, " ", "", .)

foreach x in "ACUTEOVER" "ALOHAHEY" "SOMETHING" {
    replace stringvar = subinstr(stringvar, "`x'", "", .)
}

replace stringvar = subinstr(stringvar, ";", " ", 1)

list

     +------------------+
     |        stringvar |
     |------------------|
  1. |   JEAN SEBASTIEN |
  2. | JERARD DEPARTIER |
  3. |    Etienne ANSEL |
     +------------------+
```

Note that the names used in this answer are fictional French!